# Screwed up partitions

Tags: gparted

I'm using an iMac

Using ubuntu, I made a bootable gparted usb (via unetbootin) to partition my hard drive. I reduced the size of my ubuntu partition and added two hfs+ primary partitions.

Now, even after removing the two other partitions, and making the ubuntu partition bigger, it won't boot. If I press alt, the hd doesn't even show up

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the boot flag is set for the partition where your boot-loader is installed.

Also take a look at this [GPartEd tutorial](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/gparted.html). You'll find a lot of best practice advice.